# CSMA level sniff and App sniff in Contiki-ng

Tags: c, udp, contiki, sniffing, contiki-ng

[The error in cooja](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQUzy.png)

I'm using Contiki-ng and the examples udp-server and udp-client. I want to do a couple of things:
1- I want the client node to sniff packets and then send a packet to the server once it does.
I managed to do that but there is somethings that I don't understand:
a- When I start the sniffing in the udp-client, by adding this bit to the code:

```
radio_value_t radio_rx_mode;
NETSTACK_RADIO.get_value(RADIO_PARAM_RX_MODE, &radio_rx_mode);
NETSTACK_RADIO.set_value(RADIO_PARAM_RX_MODE, radio_rx_mode & (~RADIO_RX_MODE_ADDRESS_FILTER));
```

This only seems to catch the packets on the udp-client app level, and when I increase the QUEUEBUF_CONF_NUM to allow the server to receive these packets it only captures the node's own packets. Any idea why this is happening?

b- When I did the same in the csma.c file within the input_packet function it works and it does capture all the packets, however, I'm not sure how to set up so that once a packet is captured in the csma level a node can send a packet from the app level?

2- Just a quick question to confirm if what I'm doing is correct, I wanted to enable the ReTx in this example so I add this to the project-config file:

```
  #define CSMA_MAX_FRAME_RETRIES 7
```

Will this enable the retransmission of packets? or is it doing something else?

Any help in this regard is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. From the CSMA code, you can try explicitly calling a function defined in your application's code, or send an event to the application's process. If this seems too ugly, perhaps the cleanest (but not as efficient) way is to call `process_post()` with `PROCESS_BROADCAST` as the first argument. This will broadcast the event to all active processes, including the application's process.
2. CSMA does up to 7 retransmissions by default. To disable that of or change the number of retransmissions, `#define CSMA_CONF_MAX_FRAME_RETRIES` to some non-default value in the `project-conf.h` file. Notice the `CONF` in the name of this preprocessor directive.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I implemented it and it worked, but after a while, the simulation crashes and shows me the error in the picture. I edit it the post above to add the pic it is in the link above.

Comment: It also seems that the app messages are not sent, I used the PROCESS_BROADCAST method, and I created another process thread in the app with PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT();, it seems that its the only process that is activated.

Comment: @SaraSosh Please keep a single post to a single question. If this answer was helpful, accept it. I cannot help you to debug the entire code for memory overflows or other problems in any case. However I do suggest using Cooja motes instead of Z1 for easier debugging.